# Tokens transferred to contract by mistake

Tags: contract-development, tokens

I transferred some tokens to this contract 0xd0507b66A2d4C4593a54B0fa45cBAaAC2Bb04CEA and the creator of this contract is 0x102f8471d87d3Ef344af9Bd5c0845ca0A7a1d397, and I was wondering how to get my tokens transferred back to me? Any help much appreciated. x

Comment: Unfortunately the contract doesn't have the functionality to recover deposited tokens.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to hear this, I don't think you'll see your tokens back. Unless you somehow know who the creator of that contract is and ask him to kindly transfer those tokens back to you.

Be careful sending tokens to addresses or contracts you don't know.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me, I am trying to find who created the contract. Do you know a way to do so? I've emailed bscscan, no response yet.